# Name for the piece of material located, usually, inside the collar of a jacket or coat which allows garment to be hung from a hook

Tags: single-word-requests

Most coats and jackets and many lighter shirts have a piece of material stitched to the inside of the collar which is designed to take the weight of the garment and make it possible to hang it on a hook without damaging the garment.

I heard myself recently, and have heard others in the past, refer to this piece of material as the 'thingummy'.  There must be an actual word for this everyday, useful part of so many items of clothing.  But nothing comes to mind...?

Comment: If you mean the loop to place on a hook, it's just called a loop.

Comment: If it's on the back of your shirt, is a [locker loop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/locker_loop), but in your coat, it's a [hanging loop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hanging_loop) or "jacket/coat loop".

Comment: @ColleenV: You should write that as an answer.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Neither the question nor my psuedo-answer is the sort of thing I think ELU should keep around and I'm not inclined to spend more time on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is called a *hanging loop* or a *locker loop* as pointed out by @ColleenV in the comments above.

> **Hanging loop**
>
> 1. A cloth strip at the collar of a coat, jacket; on a tea towel, an umbrella etc
>
> [[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hanging_loop)]

> **Locker loop**
>
> 1. (clothing) A small band at the back of the shirt, by which it can be hung up.
>
> [[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/locker_loop)]

Comment: You would not call the loop inside a coat collar a "locker loop".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (+1).  I'm surprised there's not  a word less formal-sounding for such an everyday thing.

Answer (score 0):

Could be called a **loop**

From a google search ...

**loop collar bowling shirt**
[image: bowling]

**loop collar button down shirt**
[image: button]

Comment: Could it be called a loop, or is it called a loop?

Comment: This answer doesn't match the question. A loop collar has a loop where the placket meats the collar, that goes around a button to close the shirt at the neck as described [here](https://retrospectivemodernism.wordpress.com/2014/06/07/keep-you-in-the-loop-collar-shirt-story/). it's common with casual shirts such as bowling shirts, that are designed to be open at the neck but still have the option to close. It's nothing to do with a hanging loop.

Comment: 'Loop' here seems to be referring to the collar, not the ??? (material allowing garment to be hung on a hook)